# NRE account in indian bank have to pay Income Tax in India

Tags: taxes, india, income, salary

Please help me, i am working in Dubai base company and my work place is any other country
Like Oman, Myanmar, etc. Only for work, i am going out side of India say 3-5 month/year. Company is depositing my Salary in India base Axis bank (NRE saving account) in USD that is converted in Rupees and i can withdraw in Rupees.So i have to pay Income tax in India or not.

Comment: Clearly stating the country of your citizenship (presumably Indian) and (assuming you are a citizen of India) clarifying whether you have NRI status or not (since you seem to spend more than 182 days in India each year) would help people provide some reasonable answers.

Comment: 1) I have consulted with CA he is telling that, if i am working out side of India and foreign(Dubai) company is deposition my salary in USD in Indian bank then i dont have to pay any tax in India. Because i am importing USD in India. Like that CA said.

Comment: 2) I have one friend who is CA and working in Bangladesh. He has suggested me that i can get relief under Section 90 (Double taxation). As in Dubai no Tax for Salaried person so i can get relief for tax in India.

Answer (score 1):

If you are travelling only 3-5 months outside of India, then you are not classified as a Non-Resident Indian (NRI) for tax purposes and all your income would be taxed in India.

Consult a professional tax advisor to see your specific case, for example people working in Merchant Navy would get different treatment.